# How to consume asp.net web api in mvc web application with kendo ui?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a seperate **asp.net web api** application. It works fine. Then I have created MVC web application with kendo ui grid to consume this web api.

Here is my kendo grid

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<PatientInfoSystem.Models.Patient>()
    .Name("grid1")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.MRN);
        columns.Bound(c => c.FirstName);
        columns.Bound(c => c.LastName);
        columns.Bound(c => c.DOB);
        columns.Bound(c => c.City);
        columns.Bound(c => c.MRN).ClientTemplate("<a class='clsEdit' edid='#=MRN#'>Edit</a><span style='display:none;' class='spClsEdit'>Edit</span>").Title("Edit");
        columns.Bound(c => c.MRN).ClientTemplate("<a class='clsDelete' delid='#=MRN#'>Delete</a><span style='display:none;' class='spClsDelete'>Delete</span>").Title("Delete");
        columns.Bound(c => c.IsDeleted).Hidden(true);
    })

   .ToolBar(toolbar =>
   {
       toolbar.Template(@<text>
        <div style="width:100%;float:left;">
            <div class="divCrtNew" style="float:left;width:50%;">
                <a id="btnNewRecord">New Record</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </text>);
   })


                           .Groupable()
                           .Sortable()
                           .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                               .Refresh(true)
                               .PageSizes(true)
                               .ButtonCount(5))

                           .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                           .Ajax()
                                 //  .Read(read => read.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "Country" }))) 
                           .Read(read => read.Action("ReadPatientInfo", "Patient"))
                           )
    )
```

and here is my controller class to call get method of my webapi

```
 public class PatientController : Controller
 {
    static string URI = "http://localhost:50154/api/Patient";
    List<Patient> patient;


    //
    // GET: /Patient/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        GetAllCountryDetails();
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult ReadPatientInfo([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        return Json(patient.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }


    private async void GetAllCountryDetails()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(URI))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var patientMasterJsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    patient = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Patient[]>(patientMasterJsonString).ToList();                       
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my webapi controller

```
public class PatientController : ApiController
{
    private PatientModel db = new PatientModel();

    // GET api/Patient
    public IQueryable<Patient> GetPatients()
    {
        return db.Patients;
    }

    // GET api/Patient/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Patient))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetPatient(string id)
    {
        Patient patient = db.Patients.Find(id);
        if (patient == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(patient);
    }

    // PUT api/Patient/5
    public IHttpActionResult PutPatient(string id, Patient patient)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != patient.MRN)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(patient).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!PatientExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    // POST api/Patient
    [ResponseType(typeof(Patient))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostPatient(Patient patient)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Patients.Add(patient);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (PatientExists(patient.MRN))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = patient.MRN }, patient);
    }

    // DELETE api/Patient/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Patient))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeletePatient(string id)
    {
        Patient patient = db.Patients.Find(id);
        if (patient == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        db.Patients.Remove(patient);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return Ok(patient);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool PatientExists(string id)
    {
        return db.Patients.Count(e => e.MRN == id) > 0;
    }
}
```

**Here, web api and MVC web application are not in the same solution.**

After googling for hours I could not get the proper way to make it work. I am novice programmer. I may have done some mistake. Please, tell me how to make it work? I am using code first approach in web api application.

Thank you.

Comment: your question is not clear. what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to get remote data from my web api and bind it to kendo ui grid in my mvc web application.

Comment: so, 2 different projects running on 2 different ports. Sounds to me like you reached the time to go and read up on this nasty/funny/lovely/crazy thing called CORS. Have a look at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ or http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/. Plenty of answer about specific details on CORS in stackoverflow too.

Comment: @MarvinSmit I'd put nasty in bold however.

Comment: Thanks Marvin. But here I want to use c# code and from controller I am able to get record but failed to do create, update and delete operations. How can I achieve this?

Comment: First: Describe what you real problem is. Your question isn't clear enough. Can you run both projects and debug the web api to see what errors you get? What methods doesn't work? Do you get any errors on the console of the MVC application?